# Using Copy(Destination:=) to copy to a different Excel file

Tags: vb.net, excel

I an using the

```
range.copy(Destination:= <destination>)
```

method in VB.Net

I know this function works if you want to copy to a different Sheet, But for some reason I can not find the right syntax to copy to a completely different Excel file

Comment: Please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167939/code-to-copy-specific-cells-from-workbook-1-to-workbook-2-both-have-the-same-st

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is copy-and-paste coding ever acceptable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401856/is-copy-and-paste-coding-ever-acceptable)

Comment: I alreadyu found that question. However, that is VBA and the functions used there are not available in VB.Net

This is most certainly not a duplicate of the second question. Im not asking wether or not I should copy my code, I am asking HOW to copy DATA from one workbook to another!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have two different workbooks open?

```
Dim wbXLsource As Excel.Workbook
Dim wbXLtarget As Excel.Workbook

wbXLsource = appXL.Workbooks.Open(strFileNameAndPath)
wbXLtarget = appXL.Workbooks.Add
```

Got this code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697729/vb-net-pastespecial-method-of-range-class-failed)

Here is another useful [link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?510652-RESOLVED-Copy-From-One-WorkBook-To-Another-Excel-VBA)